# MockMvc как проверить вызов метода внутри метода

Tags: spring, mvc, юнит-тесты, controller, mockito

Написал небольшое приложение на `Spring Boot` с `Spring Mvc` и `Spring Data JPA`. Сейчас пытаюсь писать тесты к его контроллеру с `MockMvc`. Пишу тесты почти впервые.

Не знаю как протестировать `POST` метод. Нужно протестировать этот метод:

```
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addTask(@ModelAttribute @Valid Task task, BindingResult br, Model model
            , @AuthenticationPrincipal PersonDetails pd) {
        if (br.hasErrors()) return "addTask";       
        task.setAuthor(pd.getPerson());
        return showTask(taskService.save(task).getId(), 0, model, pd);

    }
```

Не нашел в интернете (либо не понял) как протестировать вот эту строку:

```
task.setAuthor(pd.getPerson());
```

То есть я хочу проверить, что на объекте `task` вызывается метод `setAuthor` и что передаваемый в качестве параметра объект `person` является именно тем аутентифицированным пользователем, который получен через `@AuthenticationPrincipal`. Или это избыточно?

И затем проверить, что в качестве возвращаемого значения вызывается другой метод `showTask`.

Пробовал `Mockito.verify`, но он, насколько я понял, проверяет вызов метода лишь внутри тестового метода, а не внутри того основного метода, который тестируется.
`ArgumentCaptor` я так понял тоже не подходит, поскольку присвоение объекта `person` объекту `task` происходит позже, чем он захватывает аргументы.

Плюс по-моему для обоих способов нужно мокать сам контроллер, но его же вроде не надо мокать, если я его и проверяю?

**Тестовый класс**:

```
@SpringBootTest
//@WebMvcTest(TaskController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = EffectiveMobileApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TaskControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private TaskController taskController;
    
    @Mock
    private Model model;
    
    @Spy
    private List<Person> people;
    
    @MockBean
    private TaskService taskService;
    
    @MockBean
    private PersonDetailsService personDetailsService;
    
    
    @Mock
    private Task newCorrectTask;
    @Spy
    private Task task;
    private Person person;
    private Comment comment;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        person = new Person();
        person.setId(5l);
        person.setName("Dmitriy");
        person.setPassword("randompassword");
        person.setEmail("random@mail.ru");  
        task = new Task();
        task.setAuthor(person);
        task.setExecutor(person);
        task.setId(5l);
        task.setStatus(Status.PROCESSING);
        task.setPriority(Priority.HIGH);
        newCorrectTask = new Task();
        newCorrectTask.setDescription("description");
        newCorrectTask.setTitle("Random Title");
        newCorrectTask.setStatus(Status.PROCESSING);
        newCorrectTask.setPriority(Priority.HIGH);

    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Post request at '/tasks/add' should receive new Task object")
    @WithMockUser("testuser")
    public void givenPostAddRequest_shouldReceiveNewObject() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/tasks/add").flashAttr("task", Matchers.any(Task.class)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

**Контроллер**:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/tasks")
public class TaskController {

    private TaskService taskService;
    private CommentService commentService;
    private PersonDetailsService personDetailsService;
    
    
    @Autowired
    public TaskController(TaskService taskService, CommentService commentService
            , PersonDetailsService personDetailsService) {
        super();
        this.taskService = taskService;
        this.commentService = commentService;
        this.personDetailsService = personDetailsService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addTask(@ModelAttribute @Valid Task task, BindingResult br, Model model
            , @AuthenticationPrincipal PersonDetails pd) {
        if (br.hasErrors()) return "addTask";       
        task.setAuthor(pd.getPerson());
        return showTask(taskService.save(task).getId(), 0, model, pd);

    }
}
```

Спасибо.